# Detect click on greyed out radio button

Tags: android

I have an activity within my app where the user can choose between items some of which are available for free and some of which must be purchased. Items which are not free and have not been purchased are greyed out - but I would like to arrange things such that if the user attempts to select one of the greyed out items, I will detect this and take the user directly to my "shop" activity. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that when you do not actually disable the checkboxes but provide a custom drawable looking like a disabled checkbox. Perhaps you can also achieve the greyed out look by setting a color filter or similar.